# Entity Framework and setting up a lookup/list table along with a m2m relationship

Tags: sql, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I always have a hard time with this one. It is a simple problem, and I know how I want the database to end up looking, but I do not know how to get there. I have the following entities:

**Organization**

```
public class Organization
{
    [Key]
    public int OrganizationId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Industry> OrgIndustries { get; set; }
}
```

**Industry**

```
public class Industry
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The user case is that an organization can have 1 or more industries it is a part of (i.e. Higher Education and Information Technology). For the applications purposes I want the Industry table to act as a growing list of industries with just a name and id, no FKs. So, you know, a simple lookup table. On top of that I also need a way to track the industries the org is a part of. In the database it would look something like this (psuedo):

```
[OrgTable]
   ColId
   Col-OrgIndustryTableFK
   ...

[OrgIndustryTable]
   ColId
   ColOrgId
   ColIndustryId

[Industry]
   ColId
   ColName
```

The way I have it set up now created the FK for the Org_Id in the Industry table. Not what I want. How can I get what I want set up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stick with only data annotations, simply add a property to `Industry` referencing a collection of `Organization`s:

```
public class Industry
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // don't forget to make it virtual if you want to option to lazy load
    public virtual ICollection<Organization> IndustryOrgs { get; set; }
}
```

If you don't want to add that property to the `Industry` class, you can configure via fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Organization>()
    .HasMany( o => o.OrgIndustries )
    // configures the relationship to be many:many 
    //  without a navigation property on the other 
    //  side of the relationship
    .WithMany();
```